# Angular 1: referencing controller object inside template

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a simple directive like this:

```
myApp.directive('myDirective', function() {
  var controller = ['$scope',  function($scope) {
    function init() {
      this.name = "Sim";
      this.age = 6;
    }
    init();
  }];
  //define the directive object
  var directive = {};
  directive.controller = controller;

  directive.restrict = 'E';
  directive.templateUrl = "hello.html";
  directive.controllerAs= 'cus';//defining a name to the controller.
  return directive;
});
```

Inside my html template I want to reference controller variables like below (please note the controller above is referenced as cus):

```
<div>
  <div>Name: {{cus.name}}</div>
  <div> Age: {{cus.age}}</div>
</div>
```

Here is my [plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/WHXLbP?p=preview) with the problem

Why is this snippet not working?

Comment: i can see that in your controller, you inject scope, but nothing is written to the scope?

Comment: I want to store the value in the controller object and not in its scope.
https://toddmotto.com/digging-into-angulars-controller-as-syntax/

Comment: apparently a while since i was working with angular ;) But the $scope should probably not be injected then, it doesnt change anything in your case though

Comment: Yes you are right In my real project i am using scope for another reason. I made a simplified snippet to show my case. I should have removed scope since i am not using it here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The possible problem is the usage of 'this'.  Instead of using 'this', use the controllerAs variable.

Ex:

```
var cus = this;

function init() {
      cus.name = "Sim";
      cus.age = 6;
    }

init();
```

Comment: Thanks @Sarathy You nailed it I never realized that inside the init() this is referring the window. For those who may fall in similar trap here is the fixed plunk http://plnkr.co/edit/H9EoLR?p=preview.